# Does inclusion-exclusion formula holds for coutanble index set?

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

Does inclusion-exclusion formula holds for countable index set?

Here is the formula for index set of size 2.
\begin{align}
P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)
\end{align}

Comment: yes, it holds, but you have to do the unions and intersections of infinite sets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to definition of the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ you can see that

1. $\mathcal{F}$ is closed under countable unions.
2. $P$ is defined for all elements of $\mathcal{F}$.
3. $P$ is additive for union of disjoint elements of $\mathcal{F}$.

The colloraly of the definition and the De Morgan Laws is:

4. $\mathcal{F}$ is closed under countable intersections.

Let us consider a series $A_i$ where $A_i\in\mathcal{F}$, $i=1,2\dots$. The probability of the union can be constructed recursively as follows:
First step is clear
$$
P(\cup_{i=1}^1 A_i) = P(A_1)
$$
and we know for it that $A_1\in\mathcal{F}$.

The recursive step is
$$
P(\cup_{i=1}^n A_i) = P(\cup_{i=1}^{n-1} A_i) + P(A_n)-P([\cup_{i=1}^{n-1} A_i]\cap A_n)
$$
The challenge is whether this $(\cup_{i=1}^n A_i)\in\mathcal{F}$. We can resolve it as follows: from the recursion we know that $(\cup_{i=1}^{n-1} A_i)\in\mathcal{F}$ and from problem formulation that $A_n\in\mathcal{F}$. Since $\mathcal{F}$ is closed under intersections, we know that $([\cup_{i=1}^{n-1} A_i]\cap A_n)\in\mathcal{F}$. Thus, the recursive step is well defined. Repeating it till infinity, you obtain the calculation for any countable set.

Comment: You get an infinite series at the limit, and you need to argue why it converges to a value in $[0,1]$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila can you share a complete proof then?

Answer (score 1):

There are formulas for a finite index set, which aren't the same as the one you have there, iirc for three sets it is
$P(A \cup B \cup C)=P(A) + P(B)+P(C)+P(A\cap B\cap C) - P(A \cap B) - P(B\cap C) - P(C \cap A)$
For an infinite index set though this process may or may not converge. Take for example the set of integers. For reference, the formula for arbitrary n is given as;
$P(\cup_{i=1}^nA_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n(-1)^{i-1}\mathbb{P(i)}$
Where $\mathbb{P}(i)$ is the sum of P of every union of i elements.

Comment: There is no non-trivial (non-atomic) $\sigma$-additive probability measure on a countably infinite set. So using the set of integers as an example is not a good example. Defining probability for a countably infinite set you need to either have it concentrate on a finite set, or not be $\sigma$-additive.